# HTML/CSS Indentation Optional, JS Indentation Mandatory?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So when I get HTML and CSS validated, it's not required to be indented to pass validation. However, when I get JS validated, it needs to be indented to pass.
I don't indent any of my code because practically all my pages are relatively short and simple so I actually find it more effort and a waste of space to indent. However, is it especially important that I do so for JS? Is there a reason it's required for JS but not HTML or CSS?

Comment: Can you explain further, or give examples of, what you mean? From everything i've seen, for readability purposes, html, css, and your scripting languages all should feature indentation. Javascript often also does, but quite often is ignored from what i've seen, presumably because it's because javascript is one of those languages which is practically impossible to read anyway. 

That being said, if you end up minifying your work, no, it doesn't need to be perfectly readable, especially if your files are small (less than a "page").

Comment: @Spratters53 You were off to a good start but then you started making no sense.

Comment: Basically - Readability is always good, but if files are small (50 lines/less) and others don't need to read the code then it's not too important, espeically with minification, which removes all white space from code.

Comment: @Spratters I meant at validation sites for CSS like this https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ and HTML like this http://validator.w3.org/ I can pass validation without my code being indented. However, at a JS validation site like this http://codebeautify.org/jsvalidate I can't pass without indentation.

Comment: Any good validator will allow you to customise what qualifies as a error, what qualifies as a warning, and what is allowed. It is really up to you. I would consider consistent indentation to be a requirement regardless of the language used though, particularly if you're working with other developers. It usually doesn't affect the functionality of the code (python would be one exception) but is important for readability.

Comment: In that case, you're relying entirely on what the developer of the website says is true, and rules aren't necessarily conventions. Personally, i'd learn about coding conventions for the languages you use if you're unsure on them. I know for a fact that JS isn't dependent on it's white spacing, so you should be allowed to submit code on that site, even if it says "it's rubbish". Have you tried a different site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code validates on everything apart from indentation then I would be totally happy with that, especially for javascript.

A lot of frameworks are moving towards bundling and minification as a way of reducing the number of http requests and the overall file size. This removes any css and javascript whitespace anyway.

Comment: Yes, someone should create a simple Notepad type program for coding with an option to minify, for efficiency on sites, and an option to unminify, which would expand the code out for easy readability to edit.

Comment: There are quite a lot of tools out there. Visual Studio definitely supports running standard js and css in debug mode, but automatically bundling and minifying in release mode. I think Grunt and phpstorm also have similar functionality.